# Xamarin Forms - Tap Gesture Recognizer Equivalent

Tags: android, frame, xamarin.forms, gesture-recognition, equivalent

I'm working in the PCL with the last stable version of Xamarin Forms and I need to use a tap gesture recognizer on a frame but it does not work.

For the moment, the targeted platform is Android.

I tried to test the tap gesture recognizer on a label and it works.

Since I need to use a frame, I would like to know if there is a tap gesture recognizer equivalent in order to detect a tap on my frame.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bug. See [Bug 38158](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38158) for a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is a bug. Unfortunately, the workaround does not work for me. Is there no way around this bug? No equivalent to a tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: I was finally able to use a stacklayout instead of a frame. Since the bug does not affect the stacklayouts, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conclusion, this is a bug. See [Bug 38158](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38158) for a workaround. It might work for your project.

I did not find any equivalent for a tap gesture recognizer but I was able to use a stacklayout instead of a frame. Since the bug does not affect the stacklayouts, the tap gesture recognizer is working.

The problem is solved.